# Calculation of a scale mean (Children's Behavior Questionnaire (CBQ)) with NAs and "WN"

Tags: r, scale, mean, na

Unfortunately, I still haven't come to a good solution to make the scale mean of the CBQ.
After a long research I did not find any other solution.

The problem is: I still want to get a mean value for each child (even if there were NAs). So if for one child (scale with 17 items, sum of 40 "points") one item was not answered at all and for two other items "Don't know" ("WN") was given, I want R to calculate that for me: Number of 14 items, divide 40 by 14 and get a mean of 2.85 as the scale score.

Greetings and thanks for your support

It doesn't work like that in the classical way

```
data$cbq_ik_mean <- rowMeans(subset(data, select = c(cbq_ik_4, cbq_ik_20, cbq_ik_32recode, cbq_ik_63,cbq_ik_75,cbq_ik_93recode, cbq_ik_108recode, cbq_ik_116, cbq_ik_136,cbq_ik_147, cbq_ik_162recode, cbq_ik_168, cbq_ik_185)), na.rm = TRUE)


cbq_ik <- subset (data, select = c(cbq_ik_4,cbq_ik_20,cbq_ik_32recode,cbq_ik_63,cbq_ik_75,
                                   cbq_ik_93recode,cbq_ik_108recode,cbq_ik_116,cbq_ik_136,
                                   cbq_ik_147,cbq_ik_162recode,cbq_ik_168,cbq_ik_185, cbq_ik_mean))

describe(cbq_ik)
```

Because there only mean values of the children are calculated, where all items were answered. In my case, the scale mean consists of only 9 (of 27 values). Can you think of another way I can try?

| ID | cbq_ik_4 | cbq_ik_20 | cbq_ik_32recode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | NA | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | WN |
| 3 | WN | 7 | 6 |
| 4 | WN | 4 | 5 |
| .. |  |  |  |

[picture of the dataframe with "WN"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UPHR.png)

Comment: Please provide an example of your data set to better understand your problem, perhaps by including the output of `dput(mydata)` as part of your question.

Comment: I strongly urge you to [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) your data - here, that would mean having a data frame with columns for (say) Participant ID, Question and Response.   Your life will become considerably easier (and your code far more compact and robust) if you do.

Comment: thank you very much, I already have. I just did not manage to display this as a table in the question first

Comment: Have you tried the `na.rm=TRUE` argument for mean or rowMeans? That will calculate mean, ignoring any NA values: `mean(c(3,2,NA), na.rm=T)` gives 2.5.

Comment: thank you -  Yes that works. However, not with the "WN" values. These should be subtracted from the number of values in the calculation of the mean...

Comment: You need to do a cleanup of the data prior to calculation of the mean or write a custom lambda that calculates the mean excluding NA and WN.

Comment: thanks ! @duffymo How do i write a custom lambda that calculates the mean without NA and WN?

Comment: Write an R function that takes in the input data frame, iterates over it, and calculates the mean, call it as a lambda.  I haven't written R in a long time.  I'm sure you can piece it together.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry but I don't think I can do this by myself. I would also still describe myself as a beginner in R....other ideas? it's for my master thesis and there is no other way to proceed with the analysis

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added a picture of my data. Which data would still be important? and how should I insert them?

Comment: Have you tried replacing "WN" values with NA values? Seems easier than calculating the mean excluding WN. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959009/r-replace-elements-with-na-in-a-matrix-in-corresponding-positions-to-nas-in-an